# Avoid 'Discriminator' with AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, & AspNetUserRoles

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am extending `IdentityUser`, `IdentityUserRole`, and `IdentityRole` like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationIdentityUserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>();
}

public class ApplicationIdentityUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationIdentityUserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>();
    }
```

and configured like:

```
public class SmartAccountingSetUpContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public SmartAccountingSetUpContext(DbContextOptions<SmartAccountingSetUpContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Ignore<RegistrationViewModel>();
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");           


        builder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>()
                    .HasOne(p => p.User)
                    .WithMany(b => b.Roles)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Role)
            .WithMany(x => x.Roles)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId);
    }
}
```

I keep getting this:

```
"Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'."
```

I understand if you have derived class, then you have to specify the HasDiscriminitor in OnModelCreating method. However IdentityUser, IdentityUserRole, and IdentityRole are no abstract classes.

How can I get past this?

Comment: Can you show the base class definition of your context, e.g. `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<???>`

Comment: @IvanStoev please see updated code.

Comment: You are not registering your other types. `IdentityDbContext` also exists with multiple type parameters

Comment: Since you are using custom role, inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your context is inheriting [`IdentityDbContext<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0) which in turn inherits `IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>`. `TUser` in this case is your `ApplicationUser`, but the role type is `IdentityRole`.

Thus the base class fluent configuration registers `IdentityRole` as *entity*. When you register the derived `ApplicationRole` as entity, EF Core treats that as [TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) Inheritance Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance) which is implemented with single table having `Discriminator` column.

To fix the issue, simply use the proper base generic `IdentityDbContext`. Since you also have a custom `IdentityUserRole` derived type, you should use the one with all generic type arguments - [`IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TRoleClaim,TUserToken>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8?view=aspnetcore-2.0):

```
public class SmartAccountingSetUpContext : IdentityDbContext
<
    ApplicationUser, // TUser
    ApplicationRole, // TRole
    string, // TKey
    IdentityUserClaim<string>, // TUserClaim
    ApplicationIdentityUserRole, // TUserRole,
    IdentityUserLogin<string>, // TUserLogin
    IdentityRoleClaim<string>, // TRoleClaim
    IdentityUserToken<string> // TUserToken
>
{
    // ...
}
```