# Unable to Save User Accounts After Renaming Identity Tables In Asp.Net MVC Core App

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have managed to customize Identity table names and IdentityUser as described on this forum. My problem is that I'm unable to save user accounts thereafter and I get the error below:

> Cannot use table App Users for entity type App Users since it is being used for entity type ApplicationUser and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

I have included herein a demo app that can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OGHHfJKhJe8sO9mUFTUNjwfOwUSGFX6i)

After customizing table names, I did add a migration and updated the database, all these operations where successful, I then used the dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command to import other database tables. After this, I added another migration which was unsuccessful, ef framework throws the error below:

> Cannot use table 'AppRole' for entity type 'AppRole' since it is being used for entity type 'IdentityRole' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

I have reset the migrations, deleted the _migration table and started all over again but can't get it to work. I therefore beseech you to assist me in this regard.

This is a snapshot of DB-Context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.3-servicing-35854");

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var table = entityType.Relational().TableName;
        if (table.StartsWith("AspNet"))
        {
            entityType.Relational().TableName = table.Replace(table.Substring(0, 6), "App");
        }
    };

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppRoleClaims>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

        entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppRoleClaims)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppRoles>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName)
            .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

        entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(256);

        entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserClaims>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

        entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppUserClaims)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserLogins>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

        entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppUserLogins)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserRoles>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppUserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppUserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserTokens>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });

        entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.AppUserTokens)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUsers>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail)
            .HasName("EmailIndex");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName)
            .HasName("UserNameIndex")
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

        entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

        entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);

        entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
    });
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Most likely the problem is in the generic type arguments of the base identity context. Please show the definition of your context, e.g. `class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<?, ?, …>`

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, I can't find the option to edit my post but to fix the link kindly remove the last character ]. I already have ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712868/avoid-discriminator-with-aspnetusers-aspnetroles-aspnetuserroles/48713922#48713922. It's a different issue, but the cause is the same. You should inherit [`IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TRoleClaim,TUserToken>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and designate all generic type arguments with your custom types inheriting from them.

Comment: Kindly help me understand something, remember these new entities were autogenerated by the Scaffold command, are you saying I should instead use them to override the default implementation of DBContext, replacing the Generic T type with entities generated by DB Scaffold command

Comment: Well, I don't use scaffolding, so all I can say is that you have to change your db context definition (scaffolded or not) to inherit the `IdentityDbContext` with proper generic type arguments. See [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2) topic.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, this IdentityDbContext<AppUsers, AppRoles, string, AppUserClaims, AppUserRoles, AppUserLogins, AppRoleClaims, AppUserTokens> solved the error, another mistake I made was that I was using ApplicationUser Entity but it does not have a corresponding database entity, so replacing it with AppUsers which now directly inherits from IdentityUser<string> helped. I'm a happy guy now. I have struggled with this for the past two weeks.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Please post that as an answer, so yaddly can accept it.

Comment: Just one last comment to @IvanStoev there is nothing wrong with scaffolding, I use database first approach, this helps me bring my database and models in sync without any sweat, the issue was the symbiotic relationship between Identity framework and customized table names. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome :) Note that I didn't say there is something wrong with scaffolding, just I don't  use it (hence have no experience with that subject). Since my comments were just guiding, I would suggest you posting and accepting a self answer explaining what was the issue and how you resolved it (to help the future readers with similar issue).

Comment: @IvanStoev Jus a side note : Scaffolding also helps preserve the table structure and relationships of Identity tables in the new auto-generated identity entities

Answer (score 2):

Good day, here is a detailed guideline to anyone who wants to use database first approach with custom Identity tables using Asp.Net Core 2.2 and ef core.

Step 1 ==> Create your database first and add all the tables, relationships, and constraints

step 2 ==> assuming you have added all ef framework dependencies, head over to Visual Studio and create one class called e.g ApplicationUser that inherits from IdentityUser, also add custom fields there.

step 3 ==> configure your DB context class to use ApplicationUser and do the same in Startup.cs when registering **AddDbContext** service and also use OnModelCreating to **customize Identity table names**. Remember to invoke base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

step 4 ==> add a migration and update database, this generates identity tables in our already existing DB.

step 5 ==> Head over to your Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) and verify that your customized Identity tables have been added. If so, then go to step 6, else troubleshoot the problem before continuing

step 6 ==> Issue **dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connectionstring" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models/Entities -f -c "TempDbContext"** command from powershell or an equivalent of this using package manager console

step 7 ==> *Very Important*: look for all Identity table related entities whose names were customized in step 3. Make sure these 7 entities all inherit from Identity specifying their Primary key type for example:

```
public partial class AppUsers : IdentityUser<string>{}
public partial class AppUserTokens : IdentityUserToken<string>{}
public partial class AppUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>{}
public partial class AppUserLogins : IdentityUserLogin<string>{}
public partial class AppUserClaims : IdentityUserClaim<string>{}
public partial class AppRoles : IdentityRole<string>{}
public partial class AppRoleClaims : IdentityRoleClaim<string>{}
```

After this go to the initial DBContext class, the one registered in ConfigureServices in startup.cs and change the class signature to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUsers, AppRoles, string, AppUserClaims, AppUserRoles, AppUserLogins, AppRoleClaims, AppUserTokens>
```

Step 8: copy all the DbSet and everything method inside OnModelCreating from temporary **TempDBContext** auto-generated by the **scaffold** command in step 6 and replace what you have in your initial DBContext or you could alternatively make **TempDBContext** your main DBContext but remember to update ConfigureServices.

step 9: Update all references to **ApplicationUser** and make them point to **AppUsers**, copy all custom fields from **ApplicationUser** to **AppUsers**, the reason for doing this is that **ApplicationUser** doesn't have a reference table to map to in the database but **AppUsers** does.

step 10 ==> Update all your views and partial views injected with

```
@inject SignInManager<AppUsers> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AppUsers> UserManager
```

to use **AppUsers** from **ApplicationUser** especially _LoginPartial.cshtml and you are done. you can now add user Accounts as follows:

```
var user = new AppUsers
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserName = "example@gmail.com",
                    Email = "example@gmail.com",
                    PhoneNumber = "0123456789",
                };

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Ex@mple88@gmail.com");
```

Done!!! do some code clean-up and delete any files and code no longer needed, this is how I succeeded to make Identity work using Custom Table Names and DB first approach. Failure to follow these steps to the later will result in errors I posted and many others. Thank you for reading through.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table names using the below:

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);

builder.Entity<UserProfile>().ToTable("UserProfile");
builder.Entity<UserProfile>().Property(up => up.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
builder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("Role").Property(ur => ur.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
builder.Entity<UserRole>().Property(ur => ur.Id).HasColumnName("UserRoleId");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(k => new {k.RoleId, k.UserId});
builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>().ToTable("UserToken");
```

Ref: 
https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2017/09/05/taking-control-of-aspnet-identity-table-names

Comment: Good day, thank you for the response, the tables are renamed successfully using the loop, the challenge is solving the errors in bold.

Comment: I think the problem is occurring because both you and the identity framework are trying to create the same table. using the above approach should negate that. unless I'm missing something

Comment: The root of the problem was that I didn't know that I have to inherit/sub-class from all the Identity entities since I have changed the default naming conversion used by Identity, I wanted more control. IdentityDbContext<AppUsers, AppRoles, string, AppUserClaims, AppUserRoles, AppUserLogins, AppRoleClaims, AppUserTokens>, was the solution.