# Update-Database fails in EF Core when creating database generated integer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.0. I have an AppUser, which extends Microsoft's IdentityUser.
I have to integrate with another API, which forces me to represent
my AppUser with an integer ID. My AppUser PK however, is a string.
I've come up with an idea, that my AppUser will also contain a property
named ShortId, which will be an integer generated by the database when
inserting.
My class declaration therefore looks like this:

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        ...
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ShortId { get; set; }
    }
```

However, after adding migration and running Update-Database there's an error saying

```
Could not create IDENTITY attribute on nullable column 'ShortId', table 'AspNetUsers'.
```

I've clearly marked my column with **[Required]** attribute, therefore it should be clear that this column is not nullable. However, SQL insert statement still looks like this, which seems to produce an error:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
...
[ShortId] int NULL IDENTITY,
... )
```

Comment: Do you see column named `Discriminator` in the above `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Yes I do, additionally, when I manually add NOT NULL IDENTITY instead of NULL IDENTITY then create table works.

Comment: `NULL` and `Discriminator` indicate EF Core tries to implement Table Per Hierarchy inheritance strategy. This happens when you don't inherit the proper identity context with proper generic type arguments. Can you post the definition of your `DbContext` - just the base part, e.g. `class MyDbContext : …`

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext { ... }

Comment: And it should be `:  IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712868/avoid-discriminator-with-aspnetusers-aspnetroles-aspnetuserroles for explanation and options

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now!